# Caffe make runtest loops

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to work with caffe. make and make test succeed. When I run 'make runtest' it seems to go into an infinite loop.
[image: Screenshot of the make runtest looping]

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo make clean 
sudo make all
sudo make pycaffe
sudo make distribute
sudo make test
sudo make runtest
```

Answer (score 0):

just run "make runtest". It should work.